# Display sale items on shop page in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I'm trying to figure out a direct link to display all sale items in the shop. URLs can usually filter out specific attributes and queries, so I was hopeful that this would be possible. So far, no luck.

My result turns up: no products found. But there are indeed products on sale.

I've tried the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'filter_on_sale_products', 20, 1 );
function filter_on_sale_products( $meta_query ){
    if( isset($_GET['onsale']) && $_GET['onsale'] ){
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key' => '_sale_price',
            'value' => 0,
            'compare' => '>'
        );
    }
    return $meta_query;
}
```

This should return all sale items by URL: https://www.example.com/shop/?onsale=1

Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Your code contains some very minor errors.

You can use the `woocommerce_product_query` action hook instead. This should suffice:

```php
function action_woocommerce_product_query( $q ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) return;

    // Isset & NOT empty
    if ( isset( $_GET['onsale'] ) ) {
        // Equal to 1
        if ( $_GET['onsale'] == 1 ) {
            //  Function that returns an array containing the IDs of the products that are on sale.
            $product_ids_on_sale = wc_get_product_ids_on_sale();

            $q->set( 'post__in', $product_ids_on_sale );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'action_woocommerce_product_query', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

check [this link](https://www.godaddy.com/garage/get-a-list-of-woocommerce-sale-products/) out

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
    'meta_query'     => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array( // Simple products type
            'key'           => '_sale_price',
            'value'         => 0,
            'compare'       => '>',
            'type'          => 'numeric'
        ),
        array( // Variable products type
            'key'           => '_min_variation_sale_price',
            'value'         => 0,
            'compare'       => '>',
            'type'          => 'numeric'
        )
    )
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```